# Can I hide the gutter when using "scroll-bar gutter: stable"?

Tags: html, css

## Problem

To avoid the appearance and disappearance of the scrollbar changing my layout, I have tried using `scrollbar-gutter: stable`. It works, but the reserved space for the scrollbar cuts through the right edge of my header.

Any way to avoid this? Can I hide the gutter beneath the header? Or perhaps tie it to just the main container, so the header always takes up 100% width of the browser window?

**Note**: To see the problem, you will need to see the snippet result as 'full page'.

Thanks,

```css
html {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable
  }

body {
  background-color: #dadbd6;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #C0081C;
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 3px 5px #bbb);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.top {
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="top">
<p>Here there'll be content. Sometimes a scrollbar will be displayed, but not always.</p>

<p>I have reserved space for it on the right using 'scrollbar-gutter: stable', but the gutter ploughs right through my fixed header.</p>

<p>Can I put the reserved space beneath the header? Or tie it to the main container, i.e. make it ignore the fixed header?</p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to remove scrolling from your viewport, and instead add `overflow-y: auto` to your content. A nice benefit of this is that the scrollbar gutter ends up with the same color as the background color of your content.

A downside of this is that your header stays fixed, and the scrollbar no longer spans the entire height of the page, which might not be what you want. I was running into the same issue, but in my case the header and content both have the same color. So having a scrollbar that's smaller than the page looks really weird.

I ended up just completely removing `scrollbar-gutter: stable` because I was constantly running into issues:

- Backdrops with `inset: 0` were not extending to the edges of the screen.
- Side menus with `position: fixed` had a weird edge on the left side.
- Even the `::backdrop` pseudo element for `<dialogs>` are not spared and show a white edge where the scrollbar would be.

If you must, you can use the solution from Anton and add a custom style to the scrollbar. But I came to the conclusion it is really only useful when either your content is changing a lot, or if the user is constantly resizing the window. And since neither is the case for me, removing `scrollbar-gutter` entirely seemed like the best move.

```css
html, body, #page {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #C0081C;
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 3px 5px #bbb);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.content {
  background-color: #dadbd6;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Here there'll be content. Sometimes a scrollbar will be displayed, but not always.</p>

    <p>I have reserved space for it on the right using 'scrollbar-gutter: stable', but the gutter ploughs right through my fixed header.</p>

    <p>Can I put the reserved space beneath the header? Or tie it to the main container, i.e. make it ignore the fixed header?</p>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **nav** with `position: fixed`, but only from the top position. So, you also need to add `left: 0;` this will shift your navigation to the left. `Scrollbar-gutter: stable;` works fine in Firefox, but there is a problem in Chrome, it could be a bug or feature of Chrome. Try customizing the scrollbar instead of `scrollbar-gutter: stable;`. The result should be the same.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5rem;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c0081c 80px, #dadbd6 80px, #dadbd6 100%);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0.815rem;
  background-color: #484845;
}

html {
  /* scrollbar-gutter: stable; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #dadbd6;
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5rem;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c0081c 80px, #dadbd6 80px, #dadbd6 100%);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0.815rem;
  background-color: #484845;
}

html {
  /* scrollbar-gutter: stable; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #dadbd6;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; /* new line */
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #c0081c;
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 3px 5px #bbb);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="top">
  <p>Here there'll be content. Sometimes a scrollbar will be displayed, but not always.</p>

  <p>
    I have reserved space for it on the right using 'scrollbar-gutter: stable', but the gutter ploughs right through my fixed header.
  </p>

  <p>
    Can I put the reserved space beneath the header? Or tie it to the main container, i.e. make it ignore the fixed header?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the little space on the left is not the problem. The problem is the scroll-bar gutter (on the right).

Comment: Try using `overflow: scroll` instead of `scrollbar-gutter: stable;` and customize it.

Comment: Visually you end up with double right padding. Is there a way to have symmetric layout and have the scrollbar appear on top without causing layout shift or pre-reserved space for the scrollbar?